# How to calculate Gumbel with LMoments and GEV with method of moments

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, extreme-value, method-of-moments, gumbel-distribution

I need to calculate the values for certain return periods of a flood event (up to 5000). It has to be GEV with method of moments and Gumbel with L-Moments. But I am not sure about how to calculate Gumbel, because I don't know how to implement the parameters and for the GEV I also didn't find any good example where GEV is used in combination with the method of moments.

Usually I would calculate Gumbel like this, but there I am not using the parameters directly:
Frequency_factor = -(sqrt(6)/pi)*(euler_mascheroni + log(log(Q)-log(Q-1)))
Q = mean(Maxima) + Frequency_factor*sd(Maxima)

I am looking for any examples where this already has been performed or explanation so I can understand and do it as well.